# auto-memory management for pointers of pointers

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost

There are legacy functions that need a dynamic array A**.  For example,

```
A** array = new A*[100];
foo(array, 100);
...

void foo(A** a, int len) {
   for(int i=0;i<len; ++i) {
     a[i] = A::create(...);
   }
}
```

I was wondering if I could use any "smart" pointers to manage this array.

I could use boost::scoped_array array. Its array.get() returns A**, and so it can work with legacy functions. But I think the destructor of array only free the top-level pointers, but not the second-level.

ptr_vector automatically deletes everything. But it does not have a way to return A**.

Do we have any other solutions?

Comment: An example of such legacy functions you speak of would make this question easier to answer.

Comment: There are a couple of different ways to implement a dynamic 2d array handled via a double pointer.  Different ones need different handling.

Comment: @AviBerger Is there any boost or stl container we could use to create 2d array?

Comment: @JoeC I don't know of an stl or boost container that is sure to do it. This is going to depend on more details: Is it a C API with everything POD, or are there classes with constructors that might throw? How is this array being built - via the API or in your the client code? I expect this will be done by writing your own container, but it shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: (cont.) In some cases you could use user2079303's suggestion of using vectors, but if the API is used to create the rows as suggested by your example, this won't work. Explicit code for handling errors/exceptions during building the matrix and then handing it off to a std::unique_ptr with a custom deleter might work in other situations. Either of these would be cleaner if packaged into class.

Comment: I wrote my answer assuming that you're dealing with an array of pointers to arrays (which is what you typically have with `T**` pointers). If my answer is not appropriate for your case, then you should show how the inner pointers are deleted manually so that we can show how to do it automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the API creates the objects using a call like `A::create(...)` which returns a pointer, then surely the API has a complementary call to destroy the objects such as `A::destroy(ptr)`. In that case, the following custom deleter should be appropriate:

```
std::unique_ptr<A*, void(*)(A**)> array_ptr(
    new A*[100],
    [](A** ptr) {
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            A::destroy(ptr[i]);
        delete[] ptr;
    }
);
foo(array_ptr.get(), 100);
```

EDIT I rewrote my answer, since the first version seemed to have been way off.

Comment: Using vectors like this is a nice idea. The code sample the OP added to his post suggests that at least entire rows and maybe the entire matrix is built on the other side of the API, so it might not work in this use case. Some version of the matrix class you mentioned will probably be necessary.

Comment: @AviBerger actually, now that I look at it, the outer array might not even contain pointers to arrays, but to singular objects instead (which are created by the API).

Comment: This solution is nice, although we must do (array_ptr.get())[i].